# My try at the completeness axiom proof

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

By the completeness axiom:

(1)
Every non-empty subset S of $\mathbb{R}$ that has an upper bound has a lowest upper bound.
(2)
Every non-empty subset S of $\mathbb{R}$ that has a lower bound has a greatest upper bound

Proof:

Let $$L:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}:x\text{ is a lower bound of }S\}$$

x is a lower bound of S implies that $$\text{x$\leq $s$\forall $s$\in \mathbb{R}$}$$
But since L is the collection of real number x then this implies 
$l=x\leq s$ and so $l \leq s$
(*I actually blundered my way through x=l, in order to continue so if someone could explain the reasoning for l=x, it'll be much appreciated*)
Since $$\text{l$\leq $s$\forall $s$\in $S}$$
This implies that the set L is bounded above by set S and because $\text{L $\neq $ $\emptyset $}$ then by (1) the set L has a least upper bound of Sup(L).

Because $$\text{s$\geq $l$\forall $s$\in \mathbb{R}$}$$, this implies that $$Sup(L) \leq S$$ and by definition of "Suprema", this means that 
$$\text{Sup(L)$\geq $ l $\forall $ l $\in $L}$$ or equivalently that Sup(L) is at least greater than or equal to all lower bound of set S.

How should I continue?

Comment: I don't think your statement (2) is correct.

Comment: It was a typo. It has been corrected.

Comment: since your $x$ is a candidate in $L$ that is why $x$ is equal to some $l$ in $L$

Comment: Normally I take (1) as the completeness axiom. So what do you mean by 'completeness axiom', if you are to prove (1) using it?

Comment: It's unclear what you assume about ${\mathbb R}$, and what you want to prove.